# CameraCaptureUI.captureFileAsync fails to return IAsyncOperation object

Tags: windows-8, winjs

For some reason, my code is unable to retrieve the IAsyncOperation object that is returned upon calling captureFileAsync method of the Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI() method.  The IAsyncOperation object is returned according to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureui.capturefileasync.aspx).  In that documentation link, it states:

```
Return value
Type: IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>
When this operationcompletes, a StorageFile object is returned.
```

So here is my code:

```js
var dialog = new Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();
var aspectRatio = { width: 4, height: 3 };

dialog.photoSettings.croppedAspectRatio = aspectRatio;
appSession.InAsyncMode = dialog.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo).done(function (file) {
        if (file) {
            self.addPage(URL.createObjectURL(file));
        } else {
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("No photo captured.", "sample", "status");
        }
    }, function (err) {
            // None taken
    });
```

When I inspect the value of appSession.InAysncMode, I see that the function returns `undefined`.  I suspect it returns `undefined` because the operation is not complete (i.e. the user has not yet created the photo, and it has not been saved to disc), but I need it in order to cancel out of the camera capture mode programmatically.  Does anybody know why it would return undefined instead of the documented IAsyncOperation object?

Thanks!

Comment: gotta love the win8 ghost town...

Comment: I decided to post this question to those forums, and got an answer in a day!  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e8e77027-6416-4b08-8ca4-bc7ecab885d4/why-does-cameracaptureuicapturefileasync-fail-to-return-iasyncoperation-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, here's the answer I posted on the MSDN forum.

To answer your ending question, you can cancel the capture UI by canceling the promise from dialog.captureFileAsync.

Your InAsyncMode flag is undefined because you're assigning to it the return value from captureFileAsync.done() which is, by definition, undefined. It has nothing to do with the API's success.

In the docs, when you see IAsyncOperation, what you get in JavaScript is a promise that will deliver  as a result to the completed handler if it succeed. You never see IAsyncOperation or related interfaces in JavaScript directly. The documentation for WinRT is written to be language-neutral, so it's important to understand how those things show up in JS (as promises). In C# you don't see it either, as you just use the await keyword. It's mostly in C++ that you actually encounter the interface.

Anyway, you I believe you want is something along the lines of the code below, where you could eliminate IsAsyncMode in favor of just checking for a non-null promise:

```
appSession.capturePromise = dialog.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo);
appSession.IsAsyncMode = (appSession.capturePromise != null);


//This will close the capture UI after 5 seconds--replace with whatever logic you need
setTimeout(function () { appSession.capturePromise.cancel(); }, 5000);

appSession.capturePromise.done(function (file) {
    if (file) {
    } else {
    }
}, function (err) {
    appSession.IsAsyncMode = false;
    appSession.capturePromise = null;
});
```